# Converting a [String] for use in TWTRTimelineFilter.handles

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric

I am trying to filter a `TWTRListTimelineDataSource(listSlug:listOwnerScreenName:apiClient)` but I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the array into a set that the filter will accept.
I have 2 arrays, `memberIDs` which has about 30 Strings, then `userFavorites` that has whichever memberIDs you have favorited. I have a `TWTRTimelineView` that displays tweets from all the members but I want to give an option to only show tweets from favorites.

This is my original code:

```
var handlesToRemove = [String]()
for id in memberIDs {
    if userFavorites.contains(id!) {
    } else {
        handlesToRemove.append(id!)
    }
}
let filter = TWTRTimelineFilter()
filter.handles = handlesToRemove
dataSource.timelineFilter = filter
```

But it gives me an error that `[String]` is not convertible to `Set<AnyHashable>?`

I have tried changing `handlesToRemove = Set<AnyHashable>()` and using `handlesToRemove.insert(id!)` instead of append().

Looking at the Debug that gives me the correct handlesToRemove but the filter doesn't work, the timeline is unchanged.

[From the documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/show-timelines.html#filter-timeline) if I hardcode `filter.handles = ["memberid1","memberid2"]` it works and removes those ID's, but I need the user to be able to make their own filter.

Is this possible or is there a better way to show a timeline with an Array of handles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Set` init to convert your array to `Set` also use `filter` instead of adding object in loop.

```
let handlesToRemove = memberIDs.filter { !userFavorites.contains($0!) }
let filter = TWTRTimelineFilter()
filter.handles = Set(handlesToRemove)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's much cleaner.

Comment: @Brad Welcome mate :0